# How to understand $Im \left[\frac{z-a}{b}\right] <0 $ is a half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

It is easy to understand that $z=a+bt$ is a straight line. Here, $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers and $b\neq0$; the parameter $t$ runs through all real values.

But how to understand $Im \left[\frac{z-a}{b}\right] <0  $  is a half plane? Notice that $b$ is a complex number here.

This a question from Ahlfors' Complex Analysis. And I show you the origin of the question below. I have trouble understanding the statement with red line.

[image]

Comment: I dont really understand this inequality. $Im(z-a)$ must be a real number. So $\frac{Im(z-a)}{b}$ must be a complex number. An ordering relation cannot be established on complex numbers, therefore such an inequality should not be written.

Comment: @Severus'Constant It is $Im \left[\frac{z-a}{b}\right] <0 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using $\Im$ to denote the imaginary part (MathJax "\Im"). Consider the usual representation with the real axis horizontal and the imaginary axis vertical.

$\Im (z) < 0$ is the half plane down of the real axis.

$\Im (z-a) < 0$ moves the above half plane, it is now the half plane down of a horizontal axis going through $a$.

Division by $b$ is the same as multiplication with $1/b$. Geometrically, if $1/b=re^{i\phi}$, that is rotation around the origin with angle $\phi$, then stretching with factor $r$. Both of these operations transform a half plane into a half plane, so indeed

$$\Im (\frac{z-a}b) < 0$$

is a half plane, but which? It should be clear that the boundary of that half plane is where $\Im (\frac{z-a}b) = 0$ holds, but that is exatly the set of points with $z=a+bt$, because exactly then we have $\frac{z-a}b = t \in \mathbb R$ and $t \in \mathbb R \iff \Im(t)=0$.

Which one is the left/right half plane is a bit harder to determine. Let's say I trust Ahlfors on that one, maybe somebody else can make a good argument why that is true.

Comment: It's a great explanation! Thank you!

Comment: The orientation works similarly: $\Im z < 0$ is the right half plane, because it contains $-i$ and the $\mathbb{R}$-basis $(1, -i)$ is negatively oriented. Moving the plane to $\Im(z - a) < 0$ doesn't change which part is left or right, and rotating and scaling preserve the orientation as well, so $\Im((z - a)/b) < 0$ is the right half-plane.

Comment: $\Im z$ is the **lower** half plane. I made the mistake myself, because $\Re z < 0$ is the much more common distinction.

Comment: @Ingix. Oops. In my head I thought I was looking in the direction of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector $1$, from which point of view the lower half plane is to the right. But that is obviously more confusing than what everyone means by "right" half plane. :) In any case the orientation explanation still works.